# Unsolicited UDP traffic from ISP

Tags: networking, router, ip

Starting from the last week, I'm seeing increased UDP traffic on ISP side of my home network and can't identify the source and reason.

Related information about the topology:

ISP -> Fiber to the building -> ISP's utility cabinet -> CAT6 cable -> Mikrotik Router (Port *ether1*) -> PPPoE Client for Internet (also runs on mikrotik)

The traffic that I'm seeing is at *ether1* port, from ISP side. I'm only using this port for PPPoE, but the traffic is something else, fluctating between 10Mbps to 500Mbps. In other words, it is unrelated with my actual Internet usage. Even if I disable the PPPoE client (== my Internet) it is there.

The destination port shows 5000, I found that is related with UPnP but I think it shouldn't appear at that port.

[ether1 traffic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiB3x.png)

[Wireshark sample of said traffic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uUp8.png) (I briefly forwarded all ether1 traffic to my PC using mikrotik packet sniffer for capturing this)

I don't even see a performance hit from this issue, but I'm curious about what causes that. Also I'm not the source, nor the destination for this traffic, so why I do see this?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: That’s multicast. I would guess that someone on your building’s Ethernet LAN is transmitting a multicast video stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your ISP also providing the IPTV services ?

This looks as IPTV streams to the customer's STBs (set-top-boxes). All are on the same VLAN, sources are from different port but from one or few IPs of headends and destinations are on various IP but always on the same port.

When customer selects the channel the STB sends multicast join request and network equipment in your basement (ISP's cabinet) accepts the stream and distributes it to the local ethernet network (your ether1) of your building.

Speeds seems about right although this one of 27Mbit is somewhat high. Around 8Mbit seems about right for 720p stream. Lower rates from 2-4 Mbit are probably SD streams.

I must say that this definitely **is not** typical network configuration.

You should be having the proper CPE that would have need to be properly configured for your level of service and if you aren't paying for IPTV service your CPE should not be joined to the IPTV VLAN (id:103 in your case).

Also, it is wierd that source and destination IPs are from public range - typically ISPs uses private ranges for STBs and headends - mostly 10.x.x.x.

What level of access do you have on your Mikrotik router ? And who have provided the router - ISP or you ?

If you have admin on the router you can bind the IPTV vlan to the one of the ethernet ports and watch the streams.

But this looks as some kind of misconfiguration of the ISP's networking equipment. Most likely it will go away after they find out about it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The ISP forces their subscribers for using their routers (rebranded&locked down) but I'm using my equipment (mikrotik) using MAC clone. The ISP also provides IPTV services and I'm able to confirm it the 103 VLAN id indeed used for video streams shortly after I wrote the question. I'm not paying for IPTV and I don't have the required STB. I tried the "join" this VLAN but ISP immediately detected and disabled my entire WAN port (and my Internet). I needed to wait 2 days for a ISP technician to physically change my port at the basement cabinet. Not going to try it again :)

Comment: Ups, definitely better not to mess around that anymore :) There are various types of configuration that ISPs uses. Yet, I still don't understand why they haven't isolated traffic for each port to avoid overloading the "local" network. Since you have said that the multicast could reach up to 500Mbps and I presume that ether1 is at 1Gbps that they are easily reaching half of the total capacity.

Answer (score -1):

This may be due to a worm.

> Two very different worms are currently responsible for the rapid 
>   increase in port 5000 scans. The first, 'Bobax', uses port 5000 to 
>   identify Windows XP systems. Windows XP uses port 5000 (TCP) for 
>   'Universal Plug and Play (UPnP)'. By default, UPnP is enabled. The 
>   second worm, 'Kibuv', will use an old vulnerability in Windows XP's 
>   UPnP implementation to exploit systems. This vulnerability was one
>   of the first discovered in Windows XP and patches have been available.

References:
[1] https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/Port+5000+increase+due+to+two+worms+Bobax+and+Kibuv/198/

Comment: Ok, just updated the answer with the relevant information.